# Mysql query insert multiple table same id

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have two table in my mysql database and when I add a new post (by PHP) a new row is created in it:

```
-Post(ID,title,body)

-pictures(id,id_post,path_picture)
```

How could I achieve to pass the `post ID` to the relative `pictures id_post` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you insert the post you can call `last_insert_id` to get the ID the post got.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert into two tables using DML anyway.

To readback the insert_id assigned, perform the insert then call mysql_insert_id()

If you don't want to poll the insert_id from your PHP code, then you'll need to create a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what database library you use you can find out the id of the inserted row.

For example with the mysql library that PHP provides you run mysql_insert_id() right after the query to insert the post is run.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

```
$inserted = mysql_query( $insert_sql );
if ( $inserted )
{
     $Post_inserted_id = mysql_insert_id();
}
```